# Network interface eth0 not up at start on Debian 6

Tags: debian, networking

I have Debian 6.0. In my interfaces file (`/etc/network/interfaces`) I have the following lines:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.8
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Every time I start the computer, `eth0` is not working.

When I enter `ifconfig -a`, `eth0` is not "up" and "running".

I have to enter:

```
 ifconfig eth0 up
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

... and then it works.

How do I have to change the config in order to have a working `eth0` in the beginning?

Comment: i guess it's related to your driver card.before `ifconfig eth0 up` use dmesg and see up it's alias names?

Comment: What is the networking service status before restart?

Comment: Is there anything about eth0 in the system logs (`/var/log/*`)? If you run `/etc/init.d/networking start` while eth0 is down, do you get any error message? Is there another network interface (besides `lo`)?

Comment: please put all of `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Please show the output of `ifup -v eth0` after startup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I have to change the config in order to have a working "eth0" **in the beginning**?

Whenever I hear "in the beginning" it reminds of `rc.local`.

This is not really a direct answer for solving your problem but it seems that you're experiencing some difficulties with the driver.

For a quick fix, why not using `rc.local`? if your problem gets solved by typing those 2 commands every time you boot into your box then add them at the end of `/etc/rc.local`.

For an in-depth fix for your problem, first and before everything else do a:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

I had the same issue in my Backtrack, it solved after update. Apparently the same topic discussed here: [Debian not starting eth0 at boot](http://lists.slug.org.au/archives/slug/2004/04/msg00098.html)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` or better `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` (for most practical purposes)?

Comment: The referenced linkis broken...

Answer (score 11):

add following line to /etc/network/interfaces :

```
allow-hotplug eth0
```

Source:man interfaces

> lines beginning with "allow-" are used to identify interfaces that
>   should be brought up automatically by various  subsytems. This  may 
>   be  done using a command such as "ifup --allow=hotplug eth0 eth1",
>   which will only bring up eth0 or eth1 if it is listed in an
>   "allow-hotplug" line. Note that "allow-auto" and "auto" are synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that it is not disabled in the networking-scripts configs. Do this:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

See if `ONBOOT="yes"`. If it says "no" then it is disabled at startup.

Here's my ifcfg-eth0 file as a reference:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
BROADCAST="192.168.254.255"
DNS1="192.168.254.25"
GATEWAY="192.168.254.254"
HWADDR="F2:24:08:AE:93:10"
IPADDR="192.168.254.236"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

then do:

```
sudo service network restart
```

Ip address is not static set and won't change after reboot.

Comment: Debian does not use sysconfig or redhat's configuration scripts.

Comment: it's for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora not for Debian based system's

Answer (score 1):

Is network service is enable at startup ?

Try using `sysv-rc-conf` Or `rcconf`  tools

Or do it manually using :

```
sudo update-rc.d network defaults
```

Comment: update-rc.d: command not found

Comment: `update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/network` Debian 6